# Удаление полей из дополнительной таблицы. Связь многие ко многим

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

***Модель***

```
  public class Role
{
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Role1 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }

    public Role()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
    public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastAuthorizationTime { get; set; }
    public int VisitCount { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public User()
    {
        Roles = new List<Role>();
    }
}
    public class UsersRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public UsersContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(c => c.Users)
            .WithMany(s => s.Roles)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("RoleId")
            .MapRightKey("UserId")
            .ToTable("UsersRole"));
    }
}
```

***Удаление в контроллере***

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Roles = db.Roles.ToList();
        return View(user);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Find(id);
        db.Users.Remove(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Что и где изменить, для удаления не только с Users как это происходит сейчас, но и убрать данные по этому пользователю с UsersRole. Что-то вроде такого на сколько я понимаю :

```
            UsersRole role = db.Users.Where(g => g.UserId == id);
        db.UsersRole.Remove(role);
```

Нужно изменить контекст? Прошу максимально просто с примером. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

Заклинило. Решение:

```
user.Roles.Clear();
```